# help with lambda in forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a select box which has its options from a model called "Event". On my production server the result gets chached.

I need on every request the newest version of all Events in this select box. I asked in #django and someone said I should use lambda. I tried this with lambda but it doesn't work. Still get old values when I add a new Event only an apache restart show me the newest version.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
#forms.py

events = lambda : [(e.id, e.title) for e in Event.objects.all().order_by('-date')]

class EventForm(Form):
    event_title = ChoiceField(label='Veranstaltung', choices=events())
```

Answer (score 1):

Grrr... comment boxes give me very little room for editing. I'll try it here:

The workaround is to use the `__init__` of the form, i.e.

```
class EventForm(Form):
    event_title = ChoiceField(label='Veranstaltung', choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['events'].choices = [(e.id, e.title) for e in Event.objects.all().order_by('-date')]
```

By the way, did you consider using a `ModelChoiceField`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I didn't realize the existence of ModelChoiceField. :)

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWER WILL NOT WORK, see comments

You're evaluating the lambda, rendering it useless.

Drop the brackets like so:

```
event_title = ChoiceField(label='Veranstaltung', choices=events)
```

Good luck!

Comment: When I do that I get this error: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: Mwegh you're right. We should really file a bug for this, I run into this all the time

Comment: My other lambda syntax works fine for me except this beast :)

Comment: You're lambda is fine, it's just that Django does not expect a lambda here (though it does allow it in other places).